# How do I compute the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix in javascript?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Currently I am trying to do polynomial regression in p5js, but I can't quite figure out how I should find the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix in p5js. I am currently using the equation presented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates.

Can anyone help? I don't want to use machine learning for this as I am doing this for a highschool linear algebra class.

Comment: I'm not sure the scale of your problem (or the dimension of the matrix), but if not so big, you can just construct the matrix `X` and then compute the regression coefficients by using [Math.js](https://mathjs.org/); for example, it has matrix inversion, https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/inv.html.

Comment: would that work for a vandermonde matrix given that it is not square?

Comment: As far as I understand, `X` is an (m x n) matrix, so `X^T X` is (n x n), so the inversion of a square matrix is enough. (Am I right?) I guess the library provides normal matrix manipulations (multiplication and transpose) for non-square matrices.